# Elementor - Vertical Nav Menu - Sub Menu alignment

Tags: css, alignment, nav, submenu, elementor

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYnu0.jpg)

I have the Elementor's Nav Menu with Vertical layout and I want to align the submenu to the right side. How to achieve this with Custom CSS? Thank you!

Comment: It's better to add your code. But the easiest way just add to ul element text/align, like:  ul {text-align:right;}

Comment: And if your website is online, you can put the link, so we can check where the problem is.

Comment: ul {text-align:right;} didn't work 

Here is the link:

yy-dev.binkowskiy.com